# Model's base class in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have cloned the project from `git clone https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started.git`. and i creadted the data base as suggested in [create new data source](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Create-new-data-source.html). Then i created model as suggested in [create new models](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Create-new-models.html). while it comes to select model's base class, i am getting four options. they are `Model`, `PersistedModel`, `CoffeeShop`, and `(custom)`. But here in creating model page it is advised to select `user` as base class. Why i am not getting `user` as a option in model's base class?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.

One reason might be because npm didn't install loopback properly or didn't install at all. After you clone it, you have to run `npm install`. If there was an error or didn't run, just try running it again.

Another reason might be because your `server/model-config.json` file is corrupted or it doesn't contain `User` model. It should have these at least:

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  }
}
```

It might be a bug in your loopback cli version. I suggest try updating it and then try again:

```
npm update loopback-cli -g
```

And if that didn't work, make bug report to loopback. Make sure give them details like OS version, node version, npm version, loopback-cli version and so on.